# Removing a variable's value without losing its children methods

Tags: javascript, parent

I'm trying to remove the value of an array, *without* removing its methods. Consider the following code:

```
var Project = function () {

    //The array where all data will be stored before they are sent..
    this.data = [];

    // ... Along with a function to send data to other source ...
    this.data.send = function () {
    }

    //Here is where the data would be altered ...

    //Send the data ...
    this.data.send();

    //Remove the data, we don't want it when sending the next time ...
    this.data = [];
    // ... but this (obviously) results in the removal of the send() function ... :-(
}
```

Which also will remove the function `.send()`, which is not the behavior I'm looking for. What's the smoothest and most proper way to dodge this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you set the array's length to zero? Just a shot in the dark here.

Comment: What's the reason why you store the function in the array?

Comment: @Eduardo That's a very good question. Simply: I wasn't thinking properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sirko's suggestion should work, but your issue points to design flaw, in my opinion.

Why not expose an array like object, with methods that never changes, but has an internal array it can manipulate at will.

```
var data = {
  items: [],
  push: function(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
  },
  send: function() {
    // send the items
    this.items = [];
  }
}

data.push('abc');
data.send();
console.log(data.items.length) // 0
```

Let arrays be arrays, and use other constructs to manipulate them.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, don't really know why I didn't do it like that from the beginning, thanks!

Comment: It's unclear to me why the array needs to be wrapped inside another object and the reimplement a bunch of array methods.  Why?  The whole point of how flexible JS is means you don't have to reimlement `.push()` and `.length()` and all the accessors.  You can just add new methods to any existing object, keeping all the methods it already has.  If you want a `.clear()` method, that keeps the existing properties, but clears the array, you can just add a `.clear()` method.

Comment: The only legitimate reason I can think of for encapsulating the array into another object here is if you actually want to hide the array methods from other code, but that does not appear to be the situation.

Answer (score 2):

With `this.data = [];` you replace the old array object by a new one and thus lose all attached functions. You have to modify the existing object to keep the properties. You could for example use `splice` ([docu@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)):

```
this.data.splice( 0, this.data.length );
```

Alternatively as Elliot Bonneville suggest you could set the length to zero ([again@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length))

```
this.data.length = 0;
```

Comment: Ah, nice!  I was hacking up (over thinking) some hideous solution involving iterating over all the properties.

Comment: As opposed to the hideous solution of abusing Arrays? ;P

Comment: Well yeah.  My first reaction when I saw this question was a healthy "wtf?" but the intrigue of it overwhelmed my brain telling me to ask Zar why exactly he's doing this :).

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
this.data.length = 0;
```

And, then your existing array will be empty with all other properties preserved.  Here's [an interesting reference](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays) on using javascript arrays.